# Diamond as a building material

Tags: science-fiction, hard-science, construction, materials

So lots of Sci-fi works use mono-crystalline diamond as a wonder material used to build all sorts of impressive and in some cases seemingly impossible structures, I'd like to ask about the science of this particular assertion that diamonds are *the* building material that makes anything possible. Of particular concern for me is that while diamond is hard it's not particularly wear resistant and I'm really not sure it's *as hard*, especially in tension, as people seem to think. So please lay some numbers on me, in context, about what diamond is actually capable of in the field of construction.

Comment: Diamond, while hardness is a huge plus, can be brittle, and of course, under the right atmospheric conditions, is flammable.

Comment: Some of the points made in answers to [What early tools might be devised on a planet where diamonds were abundant?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/89024/29) may apply.

Comment: Diamond is *hard* but *brittle* - You can shatter it with a hammer. I feel a lot of writers and creators don't realize/know the difference.

Comment: Unless you really are looking for the mathematics and empirical data behind diamonds, the [tag:hard-science] will limit your responses.  There are some on this site that will even downvote answers because they don't meet the stringent requirements of the tag.  If you don't need it, you should remove it.

Comment: I fail to see a question here. Of course diamonds are not used for building buildings for a number of reasons - first of all economic reasons (which you cannot ignore because they are a result of what diamonds are). What do you want to know? Using diamonds as bricks? Building a single diamond  house? The technical implementation? How tall such a building could be? What kind of building should be constructed out of diamonds? In what way it would be superior to more obvious carbon modifications, for example nanotubes? Could you maybe formulate a clear question?

Comment: PS: You will get one obvious downside for free before possible edits, hopefully it will convince you to tell us what you want: Have you ever put a nail a) into a wall in your house b) into a diamond? If you have answered a) with yes and b) with no, you know why one might perfer other materials. If you have answered b) with yes, well, you might be an absolute expert in diamonds and won't meet a bigger expert here.

Comment: basically just a substitute for bricks.

Comment: @JBH Yeah tried that didn't get anything I could use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look at what [MatWeb has to say about natural diamonds](http://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=d8d230a8d9664bc390199dab7bc56e1e&ckck=1) (matweb is a material property database and is generally considered reliable, although not the end-all authority). I'll also show some properties you would see in a [mild steel](http://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=098700ed63b24b14bd3bfdbec937489f) where available or another material.

- Modulus of Elasticity: 700-1200 GPa (Steel: 200-207 GPa)
- Hardness: 10 Mohs, 8000 Knoop (Steel: 228-682 Knoop)
- [Tensile Strength](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102822/why-does-diamond-have-lower-tensile-strength-than-iron): 1600 MPa (Steel: 2617 MPa)
- [Fracture Toughness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_toughness) 3.40 MPa-m^(1/2) (Steel: 80.9-143 MPa-m^(1/2) )
- Compressive Strength 8680 - 16 530 MPa ([Portland Cement](http://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=bef6d86a5fe94c91b2300ed172e2a1f4): 57.9 MPa)
- Thermal Conductivity: 2000 W/mK (Steel: 21.9-52 W/mK)

It should also be noted that:

$$C + O_2 \rightarrow CO_2 $$

This makes diamonds nice fuel packets in an environment with oxygen. This should be considered in any construction project where diamonds are available, as well as any other chemistry that the environment provides.

## What Do These Numbers Mean?

Diamond is really good at resisting deformation and thermal conduction. Diamond doesn't deform much and the strength is relatively low: it suddenly breaks with minimal warning. A diamond bridge would be fine one minute and then suddenly destroyed the next, no "bending, sagging, or groaning" to warn people.

Diamond is also terrible at resisting cyclic loads and cracks will easily propagate: the fracture toughness tells us these things. In short: diamond is **good for one-time uses, but terrible at fatigue.**

Almost all buildings IRL experience cyclic loads (and therefore experience fatigue): people walking around in them, wind on the outside of it, water and air moving through pipes and ducts, and so on. Even some fantastic applications would experience cyclic loading: using a diamond wire to hold your [rotating space station together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity) would be a bad choice because water, people, and equipment sloshes around, creating the fatigue cycles which would destroy it.

Diamond could be used in some fantastic options, however. If you wanted a reaction chamber (and walls of carbon are OK) that has some continuous reaction occurring within it for a very long time, like in a continuously accelerating [generation ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_ship), diamond is a good option.

Diamond can be used in a related field: [HVAC systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HVAC). Diamond is amazing at conducting heat to and away from things. Diamond could be used to support stuff like [RTGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) and radiator fins, combining the heat management and structural systems. Once again, it's only a good choice as long as these things don't experience much in the way of variable acceleration and loads!

Comment: Also, it burns.

Comment: @Vashu It's a good point, but the fatigue is a larger concern: you can fire proof, but you can't fatigue-proof.

Comment: Completely agree that fatigue is more important. But combustability is worth mentioning too and it is unexpected for many people - anybody understands why glass bridge is bad idea, but you rarely see burning diamonds :)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Certainly _not_ the material to build something that undergoes re-entry out of for a start.

Comment: As a construction material, SF writers may want to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregated_diamond_nanorod instead. it is slightly harder and much less brittle. It is still flammable, though, and won't conduct heat as well as crystalline diamond.

Comment: @Eth Good find, but I just assumed pure diamond. In reality, diamond as a bulk material would have defects and grain boundaries, which would affect the diamond's behavior in fatigue. ADN takes advantage of grain boundaries to decrease its brittleness, but that's more a discussion for a fatigue class and less so for Worldbuilding...

Answer (score -3):

So I read your question and it intrigued me, so I did a little digging with the google machine and this is what I have gathered.

***DISCLAIMER***
I just did some digging on google and did some (minimal) creative thinking about production. I am not an expert on diamonds.

1. As we all know they are hard, to be exact it is the hardest naturally occurring substance that we currently know of, it is a 10 on the mohs scale of mineral hardness.
2. its tensile strength is up to 60GPa (Gigapascals - denotes tectonic stresses and pressures.) naturally and it is thought to range even higher (90 - 225 GPa) depending on the perfection of the lattice that composes the diamond. For comparison, multi-walled Carbon nanotubes have been tested at up to 100GPa (15 million PSI), and steel weighs in between 53700PSI and 63800PSI. So after the math (15,000,000/100)*60 we end up with 9,000,000 PSI for diamonds.
3. Toughness, the ability to resist scratching, leaves something to be wanted, as it only rates a Fair to Good, this is not true for Ballas diamonds as they are a polycrystalline structure resulting in a greater number of bonds and fewer weak points. Long story short you hit a diamond with a sledgehammer and you have a good chance of breaking it, that being said, a diamonds pressure resistance is in excess of 600GPa (90 Million PSI)
4. For construction purposes, it is also good to note several things: One, naturally occurring diamonds range from white to black but at no point are they 100% transparent. Two, Diamonds have a natural electrical resistance of 100 GΩ·m to 1 EΩ·m[28] (1011 to 1018 Ω·m) and most natural Blue diamonds are semiconductors due to boron impurities. Three, Diamonds covalent bonds actually make it a Good conductor of heat at 2200 W/(m*K), 5 times better than copper. Four, diamonds will oxidize if heated over 700 degrees Celsius making it less thermally stable than graphite, however, with the removal of oxygen and addition of pressure, it is theorized that temperatures exceeding 3000 degrees Celsius could be withstood.

So in conclusion, Diamonds are the hardest known natural element, that with some futuristic way of production could theoretically be stronger than Carbon Nanotubes, Resist 90,000,000+ PSI, resist electrical damage, transfer heat, and withstand 3000 degrees plus weather on some far off planet with high gravity.

I just want to say that this is all just on diamonds with some reference materials, I'm sure that in a futuristic society of which you are the "dungeon master" (per se) they would have a way of making a diamond alloy with Buckminsterfullerene, or steel or something yet to be discovered. So here are my observations, my sources are below, and I wish you luck in building the perfect diamond city!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_properties_of_diamond

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(unit)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene#Properties

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_nanotube#Properties

https://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=6115

Liddell, H.G.; Scott, R. "Adamas". A Greek–English Lexicon. Perseus Project.

V.; Popov, M.; Pivovarov, G.; Lvova, N.; et al. (1998). "Ultrahard and superhard phases of fullerite C60: comparison with diamond on hardness and wear". Diamond and Related Materials. 7 (2–5): 427. Bibcode:1998DRM.....7..427B. doi:10.1016/S0925-9635(97)00232-X.

Irifune, T.; Kurio, A.; Sakamoto, S.; Inoue, T.; et al. (2003). "Ultrahard polycrystalline diamond from graphite". Nature. 421 (6923): 599–600. Bibcode:2003Natur.421..599I. PMID 12571587. doi:10.1038/421599b.

Telling, R. H.; Pickard, C. J.; Payne, M. C.; Field, J. E. (2000). "Theoretical Strength and Cleavage of Diamond". Physical Review Letters. 84 (22): 5160–5163. Bibcode:2000PhRvL..84.5160T. PMID 10990892. doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.84.5160.

P. G. (1999). Gemmology (2nd ed.). Butterworth-Heinemann. pp. 52, 53, 275, 276. ISBN 978-0-7506-4411-2.

Pan, Zicheng; Sun, Hong; Zhang, Yi; Chen, Changfeng (2009). "Harder than Diamond: Superior Indentation Strength of Wurtzite BN and Lonsdaleite". Physical Review Letters. 102 (5): 055503. Bibcode:2009PhRvL.102e5503P. PMID 19257519. doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.102.055503. Lay summary – Physorg.com (12 February 2009).

Hansen, J. O.; Copperthwaite, R. G.; Derry, T. E.; Pratt, J. M. (1989). "A tensiometric study of Diamond (111) and (110) faces". Journal of colloid and interface science. 130 (2): 347–358. doi:10.1016/0021-9797(89)90114-8.

Harlow, G. E. (1998). The Nature of Diamonds. Cambridge University Press. pp. 112; 223. ISBN 978-0-521-62935-5.

Weber, M. J. (2002). Handbook of Optical Materials. CRC Press. p. 119. ISBN 0-8493-3512-4.

Field, J. E.; Freeman, C. J. (1981). "Strength and Fracture Properties of Diamond". Philosophical Magazine A. Taylor and Francis Ltd. 43 (3): 595–618. Bibcode:1981PMagA..43..595F. doi:10.1080/01418618108240397.

Moriyoshi, Y.; Kamo, M.; Setaka, N.; Sato, Y. (1983). "The microstructure of natural polycrystal diamond, carbonado and ballas". Journal of Materials Science. 18 (1): 217–224. Bibcode:1983JMatS..18..217M. doi:10.1007/BF00543828.

Iakoubovskii, K.; Adriaenssens, G. J. (2002). "Comment on 'Evidence for a Fe-related defect centre in diamond'" (PDF). Journal of Physics: Condensed Matter. 14 (21): 5459. Bibcode:2002JPCM...14.5459I. doi:10.1088/0953-8984/14/21/401.

Taylor, W.R.; Lynton, A.J.; Ridd, M. (1990). "Nitrogen defect aggregation of some Australasian diamonds: Time-temperature constraints on the source regions of pipe and alluvial diamonds" (PDF). American Mineralogist. 75: 1290–1310.

Wogan, Tim (2 November 2012). "Improved diamond anvil cell allows higher pressures". Physics World. Retrieved 8 December 2014.

Walker, J. (1979). "Optical absorption and luminescence in diamond". Rep. Prog. Phys. 42 (10): 1605–1659. Bibcode:1979RPPh...42.1605W. doi:10.1088/0034-4885/42/10/001.

Hounsome, L. S.; Jones, R.; Martineau, P.; Fisher, D.; et al. (2006). "Origin of brown coloration in diamond". Phys. Rev. B. 73 (12): 125203. Bibcode:2006PhRvB..73l5203H. doi:10.1103/PhysRevB.73.125203.

Iakoubovskii, K.; Adriaenssens, G. J. (2002). "Optical characterization of natural Argyle diamonds" (PDF). Diamond and Related Materials. 11 (1): 125. Bibcode:2002DRM....11..125I. doi:10.1016/S0925-9635(01)00533-7.
Webster, R.; Read, P. G. (2000). Gems: Their sources, descriptions and identification. Butterworth-Heinemann. ISBN 0-7506-1674-1.

Collins, A. T.; Connor, A.; Ly, C.; Shareef, A.; Spear, P. M. (2005). "High-temperature annealing of optical centers in type-I diamond". Journal of Applied Physics. 97 (8): 083517. Bibcode:2005JAP....97h3517C. doi:10.1063/1.1866501.

Schumann, Walter (2009). Gemstones of the World (4th ed.). Sterling. p. 42. ISBN 978-1-4027-6829-3.

Eaton-Magaña, S.; Post, J. E.; Heaney, P. J.; Freitas, J.; et al. (2008). "Using phosphorescence as a fingerprint for the Hope and other blue diamonds". Geology (abstract). Geological Society of America. 36 (1): 83–86. doi:10.1130/G24170A.1.

Hanley, P. L.; Kiflawi, I.; Lang, A. R. (1977). "On Topographically Identifiable Sources of Cathodoluminescence in Natural Diamonds". Phil. Trans. Roy. Soc. A. 284 (1324): 329. Bibcode:1977RSPTA.284..329H. JSTOR 74759. doi:10.1098/rsta.1977.0012.

van Wyk, J. A. (1982). "Carbon-12 hyperfine interaction of the unique carbon of the P2 (ESR) or N3 (optical) centre in diamond". Journal of Physics C: Solid State Physics. 15 (27): L981. Bibcode:1982JPhC...15L.981V. doi:10.1088/0022-3719/15/27/007.

Davies, G.; Nazaré, M. H.; Hamer, M. F. (1976). "The H3 (2.463 eV) Vibronic Band in Diamond: Uniaxial Stress Effects and the Breakdown of Mirror Symmetry". Proceedings of the Royal Society A. 351 (1665): 245. Bibcode:1976RSPSA.351..245D. doi:10.1098/rspa.1976.0140.

Freitas, J. A.; Klein, P. B.; Collins, A. T. (1993). "Observation of new vibronic luminescence band in semiconducting diamond". Electronics Letters. 29 (19): 1727–1728. doi:10.1049/el:19931148.

de Sa, E. S.; Davies, G. (1977). "Uniaxial Stress Studies of the 2.498 eV (H4), 2.417 eV and 2.536 eV Vibronic Bands in Diamond". Proceedings of the Royal Society A. 357 (1689): 231–251. doi:10.1098/rspa.1977.0165.

O'Donoghue, M.; Joyner, L. (2003). Identification of gemstones. Butterworth-Heinemann. ISBN 0-7506-5512-7.

Fromentin, Sarah (2004). Glenn Elert, ed. "Resistivity of Carbon, Diamond". The Physics Factbook. Retrieved 30 December 2011.

Koizumi, S.; Nebel, C. E.; Nesladek, M. (2008). Physics and Applications of CVD Diamond. Wiley VCH. pp. 200–240. ISBN 3-527-40801-0.

Koizumi, S.; Watanabe, K.; Hasegawa, M.; Kanda, H. (2001). "Ultraviolet Emission from a Diamond pn Junction". Science. 292 (5523): 1899–1901. Bibcode:2001Sci...292.1899K. PMID 11397942. doi:10.1126/science.1060258.

Geis, M.W. (1991). "Diamond transistor performance and fabrication". Proceedings of the IEEE. 79 (5): 669. doi:10.1109/5.90131.

Wang, W.; Hu, C.; Li, S. Y.; Li, F. N.; Liu, Z. C.; Wang, F.; Fu, J.; Wang, H. X. (2015). "Diamond Based Field-Effect Transistors of Zr Gate with SiNx Dielectric Layers". Journal of Nanomaterials. 2015: 1. doi:10.1155/2015/124640.

Ekimov, E.; Sidorov, V. A.; Bauer, E. D.; Mel'nik, N. N.; et al. (2004). "Superconductivity in diamond" (PDF). Nature. 428 (6982): 542–545. Bibcode:2004Natur.428..542E. PMID 15057827. arXiv:cond-mat/0404156 Freely accessible. doi:10.1038/nature02449.

Takano, Y.; Takenouchi, T.; Ishii, S.; Ueda, S.; et al. (2007). "Superconducting properties of homoepitaxial CVD diamond". Diamond and Related Materials. 16 (4–7): 911–914. Bibcode:2007DRM....16..911T. doi:10.1016/j.diamond.2007.01.027.

Takano, Y. (2006). "Overview". Sci. Technol. Adv. Mater. 7 (S1): S1. Bibcode:2006STAdM...7S...1T. doi:10.1016/j.stam.2006.06.003.

Kozlov, M. E.; Uwe, H.; Tokumoto, M.; Yakushi, K. (1997). "Spin-glass behaviour of nanocrystalline diamond intercalated with potassium". Journal of Physics: Condensed Matter. 9 (39): 8325. doi:10.1088/0953-8984/9/39/016.

Anthony, T. R.; Banholzer, W. F.; Fleischer, J. F.; Wei, Lanhua; et al. (1990). "Thermal conductivity of isotopically enriched 12C diamond". Physical Review B. 42 (2): 1104–1111. Bibcode:1990PhRvB..42.1104A. doi:10.1103/PhysRevB.42.1104.

Wei, Lanhua; Kuo, P. K.; Thomas, R. L.; Anthony, T. R.; Banholzer, W. F. (1993). "Thermal conductivity of isotopically modified single crystal diamond". Physical Review Letters. 70 (24): 3764–3767. Bibcode:1993PhRvL..70.3764W. PMID 10053956. doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.70.3764.

John, P.; Polwart, N.; Troupe, C. E.; Wilson, J. I. B. (2002). "The oxidation of (100) textured diamond". Diamond and Related Materials. 11 (3–6): 861. Bibcode:2002DRM....11..861J. doi:10.1016/S0925-9635(01)00673-2.

Davies, G.; Evans, T. (1972). "Graphitization of Diamond at Zero Pressure and at a High Pressure". Proceedings of the Royal Society A. 328 (1574): 413–427. Bibcode:1972RSPSA.328..413D. doi:10.1098/rspa.1972.0086.

Evans, T.; James, P. F. (1964). "A Study of the Transformation of Diamond to Graphite". Proceedings of the Royal Society A. 277 (1369): 260–269. Bibcode:1964RSPSA.277..260E. doi:10.1098/rspa.1964.0020.

Evans, T.; Qi, Z.; Maguire, J. (1981). "The stages of nitrogen aggregation in diamond". Journal of Physics C: Solid State Physics. 14 (12): L379. Bibcode:1981JPhC...14L.379E. doi:10.1088/0022-3719/14/12/005.

Shatskiy, A.; Yamazaki, D.; Morard, G.; Cooray, T.; et al. (2009). "Boron-doped diamond heater and its application to large-volume, high-pressure, and high-temperature experiments". Rev. Sci. Instrum. 80 (2): 023907. Bibcode:2009RScI...80b3907S. PMID 19256662. doi:10.1063/1.3084209.

Sullivan, Courtney (3 May 2013). "How Diamonds Became Forever". New York Times. Retrieved 3 December 2014.

Comment: None of this answers the question about the effectiveness of using diamonds as a building material.

Comment: I don't know what kind of building is in mind, if there are windows to be made of diamond, or if it's the support beams that are Diamond, I realise I don't have a list of every possible way it could be used, I wanted to give OP a starting point to see if what he had in mind would be scientifically possible in his universe, if he has specific examples he wants I'll gladly look into it and answer questions, but as a starting point for how it might be used and some hard data on diamonds, that's what I was going for.

Comment: Links to Wikipedia are insufficient to support a [tag:hard-science] question. Answers to hard-science questions are expected to be supported by "equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers."

Comment: @Akmedrah, do you mind checking your sources, particularly "Material_properties_of_diamond"? Toughness is NOT "the ability to resist scratching".

Comment: It seems that you've just copied the list of sources used by Wikipedia, rather than sources you directly used. I'd recommend rewriting this answer based *directly* on those sources, *not* simply Wikipedia's explanation.